# Route [staff] not defined while it is in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Route [staff] not defined.

This is my **web.php** (route).

```
Route::get('/staff', function () {
    return view('staff');
});

Route::resource('/staff', StaffController::class);
```

This is my controller. The index, create page is in same page.

```
public function index()
{
    $staffs = Staff::all();
    return view('staff', compact('staffs'));
}
public function create()
{
    return view('staff');
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'salary' => 'required',
    ]);

    $staff = new Staff();
    $staff->name = $request->name;
    $staff->gender = $request->gender;
    $staff->salary = $request->salary;
    $staff->save();

    return redirect()->route('staff')->withSuccess('Done');
}
```

And this is my staff.blade.php where after click on submit error occuring (route not defined).

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="{{ route('staff.store') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="user-box">
                            <input type="text" name="name" required="">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-box">
                            <input type="text" name="gender" required="">
                            <label>Gender</label>
                            @error('gender')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-box">
                            <input type="text" name="salary" required="">
                            <label>Salary</label>
                            @error('salary')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <button class="a" id="a" value="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>

                    </form>
```

Comment: You have to add ->name('staff') to your web.php route::get.

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? When accessing a particular URL? When running the redirect() line?

Comment: Remove the get route `Route::get('/staff'...` it will conflict with your resource route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no any name route called `staff`, it would be `staff.index` :

```
return redirect()->route('staff.index')->withSuccess('Done');
```

See [Resource Route Name](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

Answer (score 0):

1st remove your `get route` all is covered by `resource`

```php
Route::resource('/staff', StaffController::class);
```

this code generate route names like

### Route Name

- staff.index
- staff.create
- staff.store
- staff.show
- staff.edit
- staff.update
- staff.destroy

so in your code you need to do this

```php
return redirect()->route('staff.index')->withSuccess('Done');
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller